# Calling a function from a string on a react state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, eval

I am using DataFrame-js and displaying a CSV in a React-Material card.
I have added an input (ace editor) so that I can create a web console to call functions against the dataframe.
I am using React.
My component has a `state` variable `dataframe` that holds the dataframe. The dataframe has many avaiable functions on it, such as `this.state.dataframe.show()` `this.state.dataframe.stats.max('column')` etc.

I have created a function that takes the input from the user, and calls that against the dataframe... except it doesn't work. I want the user to be able to type in `stats.max('column')` for instance, and it get run against the dataframe:

```
  ExecuteAgainstDataFrame = evt => {
    //we need to split on the brackets
    const input = evt.getValue().split("(")
    //and pass the content of the brackets as arguments to the function
    const df = this.state.dataframe
    //split the function names on the dot (members)
    const functionNames = input[0].split(".")
    //create a variable that references the function on the dataframe
    let applyToFunction = df
    for (let i = 0, l = functionNames.length; i < l; i++) {
      applyToFunction = applyToFunction[functionNames[i]]
    }
    //process any inputs
    let functionArguments = []
    if (input.length > 1) { //there were some parameters
      //removing the closing bracket and creating an array of the arguments
      functionArguments = input[1].split(")")[0].split(",")
    } else {
      const result = applyToFunction()
      return result
    }
    //call the function, this time with the arguments
    const result = applyToFunction.apply(null, functionArguments)
    return result
  }
```

If I make the call directly to the dataframe, like so

```
const input = evt.getValue().split("(")
//and pass the content of the brackets as arguments to the function
const df = this.state.dataframe
df[input[0]]()
return false
```

Then it works. Otherwise I get the error
[image]

I have been reading around and doing anything I can to avoid an `eval` but it actually seems more complicated to use that anyway

Comment: It sounds like `eval` (or better: a `new Function` where you control the scope via the parameter names for the values that you later pass in) is just the right tool here. Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: I can see two problems with your current code (apart from the messy parsing algorithm): 1) you are not removing the string delimiters from your arguments 2) you are not applying the function to the dataframe, but to `null` - the receiver matters.

Comment: Yes @Bergi thanks for that, nice spot, that fixed it, cleaning up the parsing function ;)